# Why do I need Razor pages dependencies to write Integration Tests for a .NET Core Web Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, integration-testing, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to write integration tests for a .NET Core Web Api I'm building.

Following the documentation found [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2) I have referenced the Packages `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` via Nuget.

However, when I try to run my tests, I get an exception with the following message:

> Message: System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.

It sounds like it's complaining because a Razor pages dependency is missing? My Api doesn't use Razor pages. Why do I need this dependency? Am I doing something wrong?

*As a related side note: What is the different between the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` and the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost`? The former is mentioned on the doc page I linked above, and the latter is mentioned under the **Test Controllers** heading on the same page, with little to no explanation.*

EDIT: I have used Nuget to install the requested package in the error message, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime`, and I still get the same error. Now I'm really confused.

EDIT 2: As requested, the .csproj file for the test project.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Api\Api.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My test setup is given below:

```
public class StartupIntegrationTests
    : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _webAppFactory;

    public StartupIntegrationTests(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> webAppFactory)
    {
        _webAppFactory = webAppFactory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder => builder
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSetting("https_port", "443"));
    }


    [Theory]
    [InlineData("/Users")]
    public async Task ShouldUseHttpsForAllRequestsIfClientDidAutoRedirect(string url)
    {
        var client = _webAppFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        // Ensure that the returned URL is an https url and that there were no errors
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        Assert.StartsWith("https://localhost:443/",
                          response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.OriginalString);
    }


    // Some more tests omitted to keep things short

}
```

Comment: Could you share the csproj file of the test project? Especially the reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`.

Comment: @HenkMollema Done, see my second edit to the question.

Comment: I don't see an actual reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App. Try adding `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` to the test project as well.

Comment: When I try to add it via Nuget, I get `Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.2.2.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp, Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 supports: netcoreapp2.2 (.NETCoreApp, Version=v2.2)`

So then this is starting to look like a version incompatibility issue? What would be the best course to resolve it?

Comment: Yes it looks that way. What `TargetFramework` is your application using? If it's `netcoreapp2.1` than you should use the `2.1.x` packages as well and not the `2.2.x` ones.

Comment: Would it be better to upgrade the TargetFramework of the app? How would I do that? Just edit it in the  `.csproj` file?

Comment: That depends. If you want to run on .NET Core 2.2 you can do that by changing `netcoreapp2.1` to `netcoreapp2.2`. Make sure you install the the .NET Core 2.2 SDK from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2) as well. Also update all `Microsoft.AspNetCore` package to 2.2.0 or higher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably due to a version mismatch between 2.1 and 2.2: you're targeting .NET Core 2.1 via `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>` but you're including 2.2.0 packages. Either downgrade the NuGet packages to 2.1.x versions or upgrade your application to 2.2.0:

- Download the .NET Core 2.2 SDK from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2)
- Update the target framework of your application from `netcoreapp.2.1` to `netcoreapp2.2`: `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>`. Make sure you do this for both your application *and* your test application
- Update all package references of `Microsoft.AspNetCore` to the latest version (2.2.0 or higher).

Also make sure to include a package reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` in your test project by including this in your project file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

---

Regarding your question about `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` vs. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost`: the `TestHost` namespace consists of a set of types (including `TestServer`) to enable hosting your application in-memory for testing purposes. The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` package provides infrastructure to enable functional testing of applications (including the `TestServer`) by way of using the `WebApplicationFactory` class.